# trying to select a single node from xml file fails

Tags: xml, powershell, selectsinglenode

Within a PowerShell script I try to select the second MemberShipRule (for UnixComponentGroup) from this XML file:

```
<Discoveries>
  <Discovery ID="Service_ARCHIBUS_SCPopulation" Enabled="true" Target="Service_ARCHIBUS" ConfirmDelivery="false" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal">
    <Category>Discovery</Category>
    <DiscoveryTypes />
    <DataSource ID="DS" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.GroupPopulator">
      <RuleId>$MPElement$</RuleId>
      <GroupInstanceId>$Target/Id$</GroupInstanceId>
      <MembershipRules>
        <MembershipRule>
          <MonitoringClass>$MPElement[Name="WindowsComponentGroup_Service_ARCHIBUS"]$</MonitoringClass>
          <RelationshipClass>$MPElement[Name="ATS.Application.ARCHIBUS.WindowsServiceHealthRollup"]$</RelationshipClass>
        </MembershipRule>
        <MembershipRule>
          <MonitoringClass>$MPElement[Name="UnixComponentGroup_Service_ARCHIBUS"]$</MonitoringClass>
          <RelationshipClass>$MPElement[Name="ATS.Application.ARCHIBUS.UnixServiceHealthRollup"]$</RelationshipClass>
        </MembershipRule>
      </MembershipRules>
    </DataSource>
  </Discovery>
 </Discoveries>
```

The string "ARCHIBUS" is stored in the variable $appnorm. 
I tried different versions, my last one was:

```
$xml = Get-Content $apppath
$appnorm = "ARCHIBUS"
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//MembershipRule/MonitoringClass[.=$MPElement[Name="UnixComponentGroup_Service_' + $appnorm + '"]$]')
```

The result is always `null` value.
It would be great if someone could help me.

Thank you!

Kind regards

Ulf

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `$xml` object is a string. It does not have that method on it because of that (you can pipe any object to `Get-Member` to see its type and methods). Therefore you need to cast it to xml first, then you can call `SelectSingleNode` on it but I would search for your elements using simplified  `PowerShell` syntax:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $apppath
$appnorm = "ARCHIBUS"
$xml.Discoveries.Discovery.DataSource.MembershipRules.MembershipRule | Where-Object { $_.MonitoringClass -eq "`$MPElement[Name=`"WindowsComponentGroup_Service_$appnorm`"]`$" }
```